# How to find actual email id from the below format using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

While debugging the code I got the sender email ID in the format below. Is there any way by which I can get the actual email ID?

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=7224F7F3CE3E44319E887785BC1A872F-
```

Comment: That's not an "email format"

Comment: Are you getting this as a string? And what part exactly do you want from it?

Comment: /O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=7224F7F3CE3E44319E887785BC1A872F-      This is a srting

Comment: That's not an email format. That's an LDAP path that points to *an entity* named `7224F7F3CE3E44319E887785BC1A872F` inside the `Recipients` container, in the `EXCHANGELABS\EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP` organisational unit. One of the entity's attributes will be the email

Comment: So, how can I get the email id from it ?

Comment: @Sunjith where did you get this and why didn't you read the entire entry? What are you trying to do anyway? Are you trying to use Exchange Web Services?

Comment: Yes I am using Exchange Web Services

Comment: @Sunjith then read the documentation. It already explains all this. Retrieve the entity and its email attribute. That's only the path.

Comment: @Sunjith if you want to *send* an email, that's what EWS is for. If you want to *retrieve* the email attribute eg for display or storage, use the appropriate calls. If you want to find who the sender is, use this path to look up the sender's record

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you help me with a sample code or something

Answer (score 0):

If this is from EWS if you make a GetItem operation (or Load) on the Message in question (rather then what is returned from FindItems) this will then return the SMTP address rather the EX address which is what your getting now. The other option is you can also use the resolveName operation to resolve the EX address to a SMTP Address  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx on the EX address .